# SwiftUI NavigationView list not dismissing itself when NavigationLink is clicked on iPads running iOS 15 in portrait orientation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, ios15

Since iOS 15, clicking a NavigationLink in a NavigationView sometimes does not dismiss its nested list / sidebar on iPads in portrait orientation. The first click will dismiss the list, then it gets stuck. You can drag / scroll the list up and down to make the auto-hide behavior work again temporarily but it gets stuck again.

Here is some sample code to demonstrate:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0...30, id: \.self) { n in
                    NavigationLink(
                        "\(n)",
                        destination: DetailView(n: n)
                    )
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("List")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var n: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(n)")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Considering how basic the code above is, my guess is that it's an iOS 15 bug but I would appreciate any pointers if it isn't. Thanks!